# ¿Como evito recargar mi componente si uso useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Tengo dos componentes a los cuales les mando datos por medio del useEffect, pero cuando uno de ellos cambia, me recarga todos los componentes y quiero evitar eso.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?
La parte que más me interesa es que no me recargue el mapa, debido a que es otro componente.

Anexo código

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";

import "./agency-detail-group.scss";

function AgencyDetailGroup(props) {
  const [agency, setAgency] = useState(props.agency);
  const defaultZoom = 12;

  useEffect(() => {
    setAgency(props.agency);
  }, [props]);

  const MapComp = (props) => {
    if (!props.location) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <Card className="google-card">
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{
            key: "AIzaSyDpiR1qDLtWRG3NVz3jmzl4tAHmCImQx7c",
          }}
          defaultCenter={props.location}
          defaultZoom={defaultZoom}
        />
      </Card>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="address-info-container">
      <Card className="address-card">
        <div className="address-card-title underlined">{agency.name}</div>
        <div>{agency.address}</div>
        <div className="address-card-title">Horario de atención</div>
        <div>{agency.business_hours}</div>
        <div className="address-card-title">Teléfono</div>
        <div>{agency.phone}</div>
      </Card>
      <MapComp location={agency.location} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default AgencyDetailGroup;
```

Comment: Podrias compartir tu codigo, para tener la idea de tu problema mas clara

Comment: Listo!
Lo anexe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primera, no necesitas tener tu component `MapCom` dentro de tu otro componente `AgencyDetailGroup`. Y tambien podrias usar `memo` en `MapCom` para que solo haga otro render cuando sus props cambien.
En tu `useEffect` podrias poner como dependencia que ese efecto se haga solo cuando `props.agency` cambie y no todoso los props.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, memo } from "react";
    import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
    import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";

    import "./agency-detail-group.scss";

      const MapComp = memp((props) => {
        if (!props.location) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <Card className="google-card">
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{
            key: "AIzaSyDpiR1qDLtWRG3NVz3jmzl4tAHmCImQx7c",
          }}
          defaultCenter={props.location}
          defaultZoom={defaultZoom}
        />
      </Card>
    );
  });

function AgencyDetailGroup(props) {
  const [agency, setAgency] = useState(props.agency);
  const defaultZoom = 12;

  useEffect(() => {
    setAgency(props.agency);
  }, [props.agency]);

  return (
    <div className="address-info-container">
      <Card className="address-card">
        <div className="address-card-title underlined">{agency.name}</div>
        <div>{agency.address}</div>
        <div className="address-card-title">Horario de atención</div>
        <div>{agency.business_hours}</div>
        <div className="address-card-title">Teléfono</div>
        <div>{agency.phone}</div>
      </Card>
      <MapComp location={agency.location} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default AgencyDetailGroup;
```

Comment: Me funciono perfecto ese cambio!!